# SELECT из таблицы только строки добавленной позже остальных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у меня в таблице БД поле `index`. В него я, при добавлении строки в таблицу, записываю дату с помощью функции `mktime()`. Можно ли делать `SELECT` из таблицы, только той строки, у которой `index` самый большой среди всех строк, то есть добавленной позже всех? И если можно, то как?

Comment: Есть у mysql такая вещь как сортировка `ORDER` ... просто сортируем по убыванию `ORDER DESC` и берем самую верхнюю запись `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSSQL

```
Select Top(1) * From [Table] Order by [index] desc
```

MySql

```
Select * From [Table] Order by [index] desc LIMIT 1
```